# Linq where clause for collection in a collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a list of invoices with a list of payment schedules and the payment schedules have a collection of journals.

Invoices -> Payment Schedules -> Payment Schedule Journals

I want to get all invoices that have a Payment Schedule Journal status of Due and Overdue.

I can't get the Linq statement to get the second level deep.

I'm trying something like this with no success (statuses being a list of status):

```
i => i.PaymentSchedules.Any(p => p.PaymentScheduleJournals.Where(ps => statuses.Contains(ps.Status)))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var invoices = Invoices.Where(
               i => i.PaymentSchedules.Where(
                    p => p.PaymentScheduleJournals.Where(
                         ps => statuses.Contains(ps.Status))
                    .Any())
               .Any());
```

Remember that `Any()` returns `true` or `false` if any matching items are found, not the item itself. So using `Any()` where you have it in your code wouldn't actually return any data.

Also, this query will return Payment Schedules if run by itself (not sure if this is only part of the expression you had in your question), not the invoices.

Further explanation: This query looks for any PaymentSchedules that have a PaymenScheduleJournal with a status in the list of valid statuses. Remember that a call to `Where()` will return the actual query items, but in the case of the journals, that's not what we want: we want all the schedules that have a valid journal. That's what the `Any()` gives us - Any schedules that have a journal. We repeat the same process to load any invoices that have a valid payment schedule, because invoices are what we're actually after (notice no third call to `Any()`).

Comment: This results in the same error I was getting of unknown variable i

Comment: The last edit regarding returns payment schedules instead of invoices seems to be the flaw.

Comment: I think I narrowed it down a bit more:
i => i.PaymentSchedules.Where(p => p.PaymentScheduleJournals.Where(ps => statuses.Contains(ps.Status)).Any()).Select(p => p.InvoiceId).Contains(i.Id)

Comment: Returns the same, I was just working on it at the same time you were.

Comment: @endyourif Okay. If you want a further explanation of exactly what the query is doing let me know and I'll add that as well.

Comment: @Mansfield can you please explain how this query works? IT helped me solve a similar problem, but I don't understand it. The seemingly arbitrary Any() on the outside of a Where throws me off.

Comment: @redwards510 I've edited my answer to provide further explanation.

Comment: @Mansfield Tip top explanation. I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `SelectMany` projection operator.

```
var validStatuses = new List<string>{"Due", "Overdue"};

var invoices = allInvoices
    .Select(invoice => invoice.Schedules
        .SelectMany(paymentSchedule => paymentSchedule.Journals)
        .Where(journal => validStatuses.Contains(journal.Status)));
```